# xmemcached faster then static object access

Tags: java, xmemcached

we have a java web application that use static object to cache values, I tried to use memecached to share cache between multiple web app, I ran a stress test comparing the performance before and after the change and here was the surprise, web app using memcached is faster then the other accessing static objects

I am using java6, tomcat6, and xmemcached

Any Idea why memcached is faster than static object access? how does xmemcached handle multi get for same key

Comment: What is your static caching setup?  
Do you mean that you use one static store to cache values? Then this is your answer - your own caching system is a bottleneck, it is incapable of processing more than some number of requests per second and prevents faster access due to locking or something else.  Memcached works on multiple instances allowing faster response...

Comment: my static caching is just an static array list, no framework, no special setup. I know memcached works on multiple instance, I am just trying to know the affect on the performance.

Comment: Do you have any locks and/or sync blocks in your caching code? What are you using as a cache store?